# how to get dropdownlist option's Quantity in jquery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a problem, I have two dropdownlist, and I want to get option's quantity. for example , if first dropdownlist chose +10 and second list chose +10 then show +10 X 2 , if first list chose +5 , second list chose +10 then show +5 X 1 +10 X 1, how can i do?

```js
$(function () {
    $('.feeList2').hide();
    $('.confirm1').click(function () {
        $('.feeList2').show();
        $('.departurebaggage').empty();
        $('.departurebaggage1').empty();
        $('.returnbaggage').empty();
        $('.returnbaggage1').empty();

        $('.scname').each(function () {
            var golist = $('select[name="decision"]').find(':selected').text();
            var golist1 = $('select[name="decision1"]').find(':selected').text();

            var indexname = $('input:checkbox[name="sckname' + $(this).val() + '"]:checked').val();
            if (indexname === '0') {

                $('.departurebaggage').append("<tr><td>" + golist + "</td>" + "<td>x</td>" + "<td>$</td>");
            }
            if (indexname === '1') {
                $('.departurebaggage').append("<tr><td>" + golist1 + "</td>" + "<td>x</td>" + "<td>$</td>");
            }

        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dFlightItinerary"> 
<span class="dego">go</span>
<div class="passenger">
    <input type="checkbox" name="sckname0" class="scname" value="0" />MR LEE
    <select name="decision">
        <option selected>chose</option>
        <option value="0">+0</option>
        <option value="10">+10</option>
        <option value="15">+15</option>
        <option value="20">+20</option>
        <option value="25">+25</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="passenger">
    <input type="checkbox" name="sckname1" class="scname" value="1" />MR LIN
    <select name="decision1">
        <option selected>chose</option>
        <option value="0">+0</option>
        <option value="10">+10</option>
        <option value="15">+15</option>
        <option value="20">+20</option>
        <option value="25">+25</option>
    </select>
</div>
</div>
<button type="button" id="btnSearch" class="confirm1">confirm</button>
<table class="feeList2">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td class="fareTitle2">content</td>
        <td>$</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="secondlist">
    <tr>
        <td>go</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="departurebaggage" name="go"></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>return</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="returnbaggage" name="return"></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: and if one 25 and the other is 15 , what did u want as result? (10X4 or 20X2+5X1+10X1+5X1 or what)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution that assumes you'll have more than 2 passengers and only includes the dropdown selection if the checkbox has been checked is below. The steps it follows are:

1. Iterate over each passenger in your list (regardless of how many) ensuring to only include passengers for which the checkbox is checked
2. Aggregate the counts of each selection option for these passengers into a JSON object
3. Use the aggregated JSON data to format the output statement

Full JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vz00u6dL/

Here is the code to generate your desired aggregation:

```
var data = {};
var $passengers = $('div.passenger')
    .has('input[type=checkbox]:checked')
    .find('option:selected')
    .each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('value')) {
            var text = $(this).text();
            if (data[text])
                data[text]++;
            else
                data[text] = 1;
        }
    });
var output = '';
for (var key in data) {
    output += (output ? ', ' : '') + key + ' X ' + data[key];
}
console.log(output);
```

The output matches your provided scenarios:

- +10 X 2
- +10 X 1, +20 X 1

Answer (score 0):

use the number() function with the val() function.

```
 $('#btnsearch').click( function() {
      alert(number($('#decision').val())+number(($('#decision').val()))
 });
```

Thanks.